# Git Push via SSH throws "Permission Deined (publickey)" error

Tags: git, github, ssh, push, permission-denied

I want to push my personal github repositories via SSH method (not HTTP). I'm having issues. I know this has been asked numerous times but I've tried all the solutions but without any success.

This is what I've done so far...

1. I've created the private/public SSH key pair via `ssh-keygen` which is named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` accordingly.
2. I've also added content of my `id_rsa.pub` to github under Settings -> SSH and GPG keys.
3. I've added `git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git` version of repository address as remote which shows correctly if I run `git remote -v`
4. I've also added my public SSH key to my ssh agent via these commands `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and then
   `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
5. I've also tried regenerating my private/public keys, just to make sure there is no issue with the key files.

Having done all this, when I run this command `ssh -T git@github.com` it throws this error: `git@34.71.63.211: Permission denied (publickey).`

I'm at lost here since I've tried all the solutions available online but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

For toubleshooting purpose I also ran the command: `ssh -vT git@github.com` and here is the result

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/<myusername>/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/<myusername>/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 34.71.63.211 [34.71.63.211] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<myusername>/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/<myusername>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 34.71.63.211:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:UVaBouJo6Hj5PeRf1dBhvCPUFWU7fQKpSc7yIYbOE00
debug1: Host '34.71.63.211' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<myusername>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<myusername>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:D7Lcobs9L0s5wny5hodYEWxYsZtgOwtati2DgQV7s2M explicit agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/<myusername>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:D7Lcobs9L0s5wny5hodYEWxYsZtgOwtati2DgQV7s2M explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@34.71.63.211: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: did you change the username here? git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git

Comment: @Dezigo Well, yes. I just used the placeholder text here in the question.

Comment: Have you tried to start an agent? by running
eval $(ssh-agent)

Comment: @Yes, I did it too. After that I ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` (mentioned in point # 4) but it is still throwing the permission denied error.

Comment: try to generate a new key again, it might be a copy-paste issue

Comment: @Dezigo Already tried that, multiple times, after removing the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` keys completely but still the same issue.  I had also made sure that I'm not copying any extra space when copying the public key.

Comment: Do you have `config` file in ~/.ssh directory?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma Yes, I've the config file but this file does not contain any information about the github servers.

Comment: ok, can you search for `IdentityFile` in config?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma Yes, `IdentityFile` has the value of `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma Well, I resolved the issue. The issue was in the config file. If you have a config file, the `Host` line should come before `HostName` in the server definition. I had it otherwise which was causing issue. That's weird but it solved the issue. Thanks everyone for help :)

Comment: great, you should post your answer, it would be helpful for others
one more thing, you said that you dont have git specific configurations

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma I've posted the solution as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. In my specific scenario I had a SSH config file (in `~/.ssh/config`) with following content:

```
HostName 34.54.65.323 # google cloud IP address
Host gcloud
User faisal
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The solution was to move the `Host` line above `HostName`, like so.

```
Host gcloud
HostName 34.54.65.323 # google cloud IP address
User faisal
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

That's weird, because it had nothing to do with github server but it resolves the issue. Thought it might help someone else.